# How to merge rows with same index on a single data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
A          B           C
1          1234        Win
1          2345        Win
2          1987        Loss
3          3456        Win
3          4567        Win
```

And I want this to become:

```
A          B           C
1          1234,2345   Win
2          1987        Loss
3          3456,4567   Win
```

Note: C values always have the same value for the same index.

Anyone can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can `groupby` on 'A' and 'C' seeing as their relationship is the same, cast the 'B' column to str and `join` with a comma:

```
In [23]:
df.groupby(['A','C'])['B'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()

Out[23]:
   A     C          B
0  1   Win  1234,2345
1  2  Loss       1987
2  3   Win  3456,4567
```

Comment: what if i have 10+ cols (with similar value) rather than just A and B. How can i do that?

Comment: @lil-wolf  you should post a new question with a complete example as answering questions in comments is not a good idea

Answer (score -1):

You can use `agg` function.

```
In[3]:
df.groupby(['A']).agg(lambda col: ','.join(col))

Out[3]:
A   B           C
1   1234,2345   Win,Win   
2   1987        Loss   
3   3456,4567   Win,Win
```

Comment: Got this error: FutureWarning: ['B'] did not aggregate successfully. It's because `','.join` connects str types, not int types. So you need to map to str first. This code will actually give you your output: `df = df.groupby(['A']).agg(lambda col: ','.join(map(str, col)))`

Comment: However, your output is not in the correct format that the OP wants. Column C should only contain one value: either "Win" or "Loss". You should not join the values for Column C.