# Merging rows with same float index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
     val1  val2
time           
0.0     a    12
0.1     b    13
0.1     c    14
0.2     d    15
```

I want to merge the rows with same time to look like:

```
     val1    val2
time           
0.0     a      12
0.1     [b,c]  [13, 14]
0.2     d      15
```

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424203/how-to-merge-rows-with-same-index-on-a-single-data-frame), I could operate on a Series by selecting one column (say `val`):

```
df.groupby('time')['val1'].apply(lambda x: list(x) if len(x) > 1 else x.iloc[0])
```

and get:

```
time
0.0         a
0.1    [b, c]
0.2         d
Name: val1, dtype: object
```

but I want to do it for all columns (`val1` and `val2`). Can I do it without looping over each column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html).

```
df.groupby('time').agg(lambda x: list(x) if len(x) > 1 else x.iloc[0])
```

Output:

```
        val1      val2
time
0.0        a        12
0.1   [b, c]  [13, 14]
0.2        d        15
```